# Crystal Report causing OLEDB connection to fail for minutes afterwards

Tags: c#, vb.net, crystal-reports, oledbconnection

Here's one that has me and our CEO banging our heads against a wall. We have no idea what is happening, whether it has been happening for a long time or whether it is something that only recently raised its ugly head.

We've been using the Crystal Reports WPF Viewer for a very long time. Years. And it has always worked fine. Currently we're using build 13.0.30.3805

Today we discovered a truly bizarre issue with at least one of our .rpt files.

We run said report through our WPF Viewer, and it runs.....

.... and then it doesn't. If you try and run the same report again, you're prompted for the password that goes with the SQL Username

We connect to an Azure SQL database, in case that matters. We have tried various OLEDB providers: MSOLEDBSQL, SCLNCLI11, OLEDBSQL, I don't think the provider makes the slightest difference.

But here's the real kicker. Once that Crystal Report prompts you for your password, NOTHING works anymore. The application can no longer connect to the database - with the exact same connection string as before - nor can the report. And then it gets truly bizarre. Just wait a few minutes, between 2 and 3 minutes, and, whadyaknow, the application manages to connect to the database again. And you can even paste the password into that password prompt on the Crystal report, and **IT** runs successfully. But if you do that, you're back to square one. The application will no longer connect. You have to wait for 2 to 3 minutes before it will connect again. Meanwhile, the Crystal Report just runs and runs, happily, not a care in the world.

When we debug our own application when it is trying to connect to the database, the error it's giving us says that the remote server has forcibly closed the connection.

We have no idea where to even START looking for a cause for this problem so my question is: **can anybody point me at least somewhat in the right direction** with regard to what the possible cause for this problem might be?

Thank you so much

Comment: I have no idea whether this makes any difference to any possible answers but 1: The two reports that cause this issue have sub reports. 2: When we run a report we save info back to it, like the Provider to use and other connection details. This will make subsequent runs faster. If we prevent this happening the reports run fine every time. So our workaround here is to treat these .rpt files as "read only", i.e. add an exception to not save info back to these ones.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled upon this while researching OLE DB options. Your issue could be related to OLE DB connection pooling (which is apparently available).

I recommend turning it off and retrying.

https://www.visualbasicplanet.info/client-development/configuring-connection-pooling-with-ole-db-connections.html

Comment: I'll be honest with you.... we haven't had anybody report this issue for a long time BUT I will +1 your answer and if we ever stumble upon it again I'll try this, and if it resolves the problem I will accept it as the answer.